# A simple minimum query

Tags: polynomials, optimization

Take $$f=(x_{1}y_{1})+(x_{2}y_{2})\dots+(x_{n}y_{n})$$

Suppose I assign $x_i=i$ at every $i\in\{1,\dots,n\}$.

Then suppose I need to assign $y_i$ from $\{1,\dots,n\}$ so that $y_i\neq y_j\iff i\neq j$ then is it clear that assigning $y_i=n-i+1$ gives minimum value?

That is is $f=n+2(n-1)+\dots+(n-1)2+n$ minimum?

If this is minimum is this **unique** among all assignments?

Comment: I think so: suppose $a\leq b$ (so $b-a\geq0$)and compare $a\cdot b$ with $(a+1)\cdot(b-1)=ab+(b-a) -1$ and $(a-1)\cdot (b+1) = ab-(b-a)-1$

Comment: @Octania it also seems unique right?

Comment: I agree it looks like a global minimum. I don't know if there could be local minimums, but then again, I don't know if these interest you.

Comment: @Octania I only am looking at global minimum.

Comment: If you want a proper proof, I suggest you use the simplex method. Doing so, you will be able to see that there's no room for improvement